# Is my understanding of basis and subbasis correct?

Tags: general-topology

I want to check if my understanding of basis and subbasis is correct. I'm new to point-set topology, so please point out any errors/misunderstandings.

> For a topology $\mathcal{T}$, $\mathcal{T}$ is the collection of all possible unions of elements of basis $\mathcal{B}$, and equivalently, the collection of all unions of finite intersections of elements of subbasis $\mathcal{S}$. This is because the basis $\mathcal{B}$ is exactly the set of finite intersection of elements of $\mathcal{S}$.

According to my understanding, if the set $X=\{1, 2, 3\}$ is given, then $\mathcal{S}=\{\{1, 2\}\{2, 3\}\}$ is a subbasis, and the topology it generates is the topology that the basis $\mathcal{B}=\{\{1, 2\}, \{2, 3\}, \{2\}\}$ generates, which is eventually the topology
$$\mathcal{T}=\{\emptyset, X, \{2\}, \{1, 2\}, \{2, 3\}\}$$

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for checking it out. This clears everything up.